# dataverse connection table lookup only account table data, while directly adding data to the connection table

Tags: dynamics-365, dataverse

in dataverse when I add a connection via an app the connection is properly made and reflected in  connection table (example:from account to contact). then I tried to add data to connection table directly to see if it will be reflected in the app. That's where I encountered the problem. when I try to add data directly to connection table. it only lookup account table data, even though the Microsoft document says it is connected to multiple tables.[snip from Microsoft documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AemAv.png).

(note:  I could see data reflected in the app when I created a connection from account to account in connection table)

My objective is to bulk insert connections after migrating data from sql based database to dataverse.
I appreciate any help. thank you.